# How to set same-site to HTTPCookie in asp.net 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am dealing with legacy code. There is a new update for cookies that demands that same-site variable be set. However, for ASP.NET 4.5 HttpCookie does not have that parameter (same-site). So I can not set it when I create the HttpCookie. I am not sure what to do... It does have the paramters secure and HttpOnly. Should I find the cookie in javascript and try to set the same-site there, maybe? that seems hacky and open to exploits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out. You can't set the same-site for Asp.Net 4.5. 
But you can set it as a rewrite rule in the web.config:

```
<rewrite>
 <outboundRules>
   <clear />
    <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=strict" />
    </rule>
   <preConditions>
     <preCondition name="No SameSite">
       <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
       <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=strict" negate="true" />
     </preCondition>
   </preConditions>
 </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```